# Coalesce in PostgreSQL trigger does not fire on update

Tags: postgresql, triggers, coalesce

In the context of a database for a paleontological collection, I have this table definition in PostgreSQL v.12:

```
CREATE TABLE taxon (
id                  integer  DEFAULT NEXTVAL('taxon_oid_seq')   PRIMARY KEY,
taxon                varchar(100)         UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
reino                varchar(50)                  NOT NULL,
phylum               varchar(100)         ,
subphylum            varchar(100)         ,
classe               varchar(100)         ,
subclasse            varchar(100)         ,
superordem           varchar(100)         ,
ordem                varchar(100)         ,
subordem             varchar(100)         ,
infraordem           varchar(100)         ,
familia              varchar(100)         ,
subfamilia           varchar(100)         ,
genero               varchar(100)         ,
especie              varchar(100)         ,
subespecie           varchar(100)             );
```

The taxon field is to be automatically filled with the lowest level to which it was possible to determine a given species taxonomy. In order to achieve that I have this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_taxon() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE
plpgsql AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN   
NEW.taxon := coalesce(NEW.subespecie, NEW.especie, NEW.genero, NEW.subfamilia, 
                      NEW.familia, NEW.infraordem, NEW.subordem, NEW.ordem, NEW.superordem,
                      NEW.subclasse, NEW.classe, NEW.subphylum, NEW.phylum, NEW.reino);   
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
VOLATILE; 

CREATE TRIGGER update_taxon
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_taxon();
```

However this trigger only fires on `INSERT`, nothing happens if an `UPDATE` is made. How can have this trigger also firing in the case of an `UPDATE`?

**EDIT**

I just realized that I have another trigger that fires on update. This other trigger is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history_update() RETURNS trigger AS 
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, data, tecnico, original_oid, 
                                      taxon, reino, phylum, subphylum, classe, 
                                      subclasse, superordem, ordem, subordem, 
                                      infraordem, familia, subfamilia, genero, 
                                      especie, subespecie) 
                                VALUES        
                                      ('UPDATE', current_timestamp, current_user, 
                                       old.oid, old.taxon, old.reino, old.phylum, 
                                       old.subphylum, old.classe, old.subclasse, 
                                       old.superordem, old.ordem, old.subordem, 
                                       old.infraordem, old.familia, 
                                       old.subfamilia, old.genero, old.especie, 
                                       old.subespecie);
                                       RETURN old;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER taxon_history_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history_update();
```

Could it be there is some kind of conflict/interferance bewteen these two triggers? My `update_taxon` trigger works also for updates provided I drop the `taxon_history_update` trigger!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @LaurenzAlbe. If you mean to run it over an `INSERT` statment over the taxon table, it simply confirms that the trigger fires, but if the statement is an `UPDATE` then `EXPLAIN (ANALYSE)` does not show my trigger as having been called.

Comment: `\d taxon` gives
`Foreign-key constraint:
"fk_codelist_reino" FOREIGN KEY (reino) REFERENCES codelist_reino(value)
Referenced by:
TABLE "especimen" CONSTRAINT "fk_taxon" FOREIGN KEY (taxon) REFERENCES taxon(taxon)
taxon_history_delete BEFORE DELETE ON taxon FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION taxon_history_delete()
taxon_history_insert AFTER INSERT ON taxon FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION taxon_history_insert()
taxon_history_update BEFORE UPDATE ON taxon FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION taxon_history_update()
update_taxon BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON taxon FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION get_taxon()`

Comment: Apologies for dumping the code - characther limits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the second trigger. It is a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that returns `old` rather than `new` as it should.

That means that the original row (`old`) will be written to the table rather than the updated row (`new`). So your update will do nothing.

Since `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers are executed in alphabetical order, the `update_taxon` trigger will get the old row instead of the new row as `new`.

Fix the `taxon_history_update` function to `RETURN new;`, and all your troubles will be gone.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Everyone's insights were very helpfull.Laurenz and richyen  were correct, but I was still not getting the trigger to work until I saw @Frank pointing me to a typo that was preventing the triggers from firing. Thank you everyone, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing an answer because my comment won't fit:

If I create your table and triggers, then do `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, I get:

```
foo=# select * from taxon;
 id | taxon | reino | phylum | subphylum | classe | subclasse | superordem | ordem | subordem | infraordem | familia | subfamilia | genero | especie | subespecie 
----+-------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+------------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------
(0 rows)

foo=# explain analyze insert into taxon (reino) values ('sapienz');
                                          QUERY PLAN                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on taxon  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=495) (actual time=0.111..0.111 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=495) (actual time=0.062..0.063 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.034 ms
 Trigger update_taxon: time=0.026 calls=1
 Execution Time: 0.137 ms
(5 rows)

foo=# select * from taxon;
 id |  taxon  |  reino  | phylum | subphylum | classe | subclasse | superordem | ordem | subordem | infraordem | familia | subfamilia | genero | especie | subespecie 
----+---------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+------------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------
  1 | sapienz | sapienz |        |           |        |           |            |       |          |            |         |            |        |         | 
(1 row)

foo=# explain analyze update taxon set reino = 'sapien' where id = 1;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on taxon  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=1005) (actual time=0.134..0.135 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using taxon_pkey on taxon  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=1005) (actual time=0.017..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 1)
 Planning Time: 0.100 ms
 Trigger update_taxon: time=0.039 calls=1
 Execution Time: 0.162 ms
(6 rows)

foo=# select * from taxon;
 id | taxon  | reino  | phylum | subphylum | classe | subclasse | superordem | ordem | subordem | infraordem | familia | subfamilia | genero | especie | subespecie 
----+--------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+------------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------
  1 | sapien | sapien |        |           |        |           |            |       |          |            |         |            |        |         | 
(1 row)
```

As you can see, the trigger fired in both `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` calls -- could you update your question with more details about how to reproduce the behavior you see?  BTW, I am using PostgreSQL v. 12.0

**UPDATE** as per your update:
Ah, I think your problem is that you are doing `RETURN old;` for the second trigger--you need to `RETURN new` or else it throws away the changes.  As per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> A row-level BEFORE trigger that does not intend to cause either of these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row that was passed in (that is, the NEW row for INSERT and UPDATE triggers, the OLD row for DELETE triggers).

Comment: Many thanks @richyen for trying it. I edit my initial post. Maybe it is important. I am also using PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Thanks, I tried the return new but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I think, there's a typo within your history trigger function. There's no column "oid", but "id", in table taxon (and therefore record variable "old"). This breaks the execution of the trigger function and probably rolls back the transaction.

BTW: Since PostgreSQL v12, all tables are lacking the internal "oid" column, as you can see in the docs (CREATE TABLE: "… creating a table WITH OIDS is not supported anymore."), i.e. using "oid" could have been working until Pg 11.

Hope this helps.